# How to assign attributes to all records in an ActiveRecord_Relation without iterating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to assign the same attribute, the same value, to an entire `Report::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

I know I can do this by iterating like this:

```
reports.each { |report| report.skip_cache = true }
```

But because the collection includes ~14,000 records I would like to do it **without iterating**.

Something like:

```
reports.assign_attributes(skip_cache: true)
```

...which raises a `NoMethodError`

Comment: Would `Report.select("reports.*, false as skip_cache")` do it?

Comment: @JoshBrody thanks but I'm in a method which receives `reports` as argument, so I have no hands on it

Comment: If `reports` hasn't been `#loaded?` yet, you can chain that select statement and it should chain that to the resulting query before it hits the database. Otherwise, I think any method you use will end up iterating through the records. Is there a specific reason why you don't want to iterate?

Comment: @JoshBrody because it's a a 14,000 records collection

Comment: @JoshBrody your solution is perfectly working, thanks. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Report.select("reports.*, true as skip_cache")`, granted...

`reports` hasn't been `#loaded?`: you can call that select statement and it will chain that to the resulting query before it hits the database.